# Python: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized - how to solve it

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to send a request to web page using urllib2:

```
a = urllib2.urlopen( url )
```

But I see the message:

```
HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

I had similar problem using request by solved it by:

```
requests.get(url, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL), verify=False, allow_redirects=True
```

Do you know how to do this using urllib2? couldn't find any solution on google.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why not just use requests? The HTTPKerberosAuth implementation is quite complicated. You might have to implement a lot of this stuff yourself if you want to use urllib2. https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos/blob/master/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i want to send some headers and json data by using requests and code:

Comment: r = requests.get(url, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, data = jsonData, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL), verify=False, allow_redirects=True)

Comment: The server returns "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported"

Comment: And don't understand this because sending JSON type

Comment: Are you trying to send json data with a `GET` request? You  should use post, put or patch. `requests.post` accepts a `json` argument, and will include the correct headers.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to post and put but nothing change , now I still the the error: "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

Comment: the code as below

Comment: r = requests.post(url, headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, data = jsonData, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL), verify=False, allow_redirects=True)

Comment: Just use `requests.post(url, json=jsonData, auth= [...])`. I don't know why you get that response, but it might be a server side issue. You can inspect the actual headers sent by `requests` via the response object `r.request.headers` attribute. `jsonData` should be a python data type, typically a dictionary.

Comment: nothing change ,r.request.headers returns different value compared to send by me

Comment: it's little strange because I do not have this problem using Grease Monkey

Comment: then  everything's okay